# Java .contains() not behaving as I expected

Tags: java, android, string, contains

I have a problem where `.contains()` is not returning `true` when looking for a substring.

See the below code snippet and image which shows variable values for the following code. The problem I have is that the expression returns `false`, when I think it should obviously be `true`.

```
if (this.fileName.toLowerCase().contains(extension.toLowerCase())){
  return true;
}
```

[image: Screen grab of debug showing variable values at runtime]

I have encountered this today, after searching the web I can't see anything obvious that is going on here.

I have tried the same using literals, but still does not evaluate to true:

```
if ("Android App Image.jpg".toLowerCase().contains("jpg".toLowerCase())){
  return true;
}
```

I have broken it down further so the result is in a boolean:

```
boolean result = ("Android App Image.jpg".contains("jpg"));

if (result) {
  return true;
}
```

The result is true, so `.contains` is not the issue, rather it appears my `if()` doesn't evaluate the boolean as true and doesn't cause `return true` to execute.

I now think it's an issue with my while loop (full function below). Does the enumeration run asynchronously?

```
public boolean isImage(){
    String[] imageExtensions = {"jpg", "png", "bmp", "gif"};

    for (String extension: imageExtensions) {

        if (this.localFileURLString != null && this.localFileURLString.toLowerCase().contains(extension)){
            return true;
        }

        boolean result = ("Android App Image.jpg".toLowerCase().contains("jpg".toLowerCase()));

        if (result) {
            return true;
        }else{
            Log.i("TEACH", "If evaluated false");
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

**UPDATE 1/2:**

I have trimmed down the entire function, with hard coded literals and no longer using fast enumeration, which still returns `false` when I expect it to return `true`:

```
public boolean isImage(){
    String[] imageExtensions = {"jpg", "png", "bmp", "gif"};

    for (int x = 0; x < imageExtensions.length; x++) {

        // String extension = imageExtensions[x];

        boolean result = ("Android App Image.jpg".toLowerCase().contains("jpg".toLowerCase()));

        if (result) {
            return true;
        }else{
            Log.i("TEACH", "If evaluated false");
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

The function does not returns `true` or does the `"If evaluated false"` Log get executed, it just jumps straight to the last line of the function (`return false;`) after evaluating the line `if (result) {`... it's as if the `if` breaks the loop.

**UPDATE 2/2:**

Quite simply, even the most simple of `if` statements inside my function would cause the code to jump to the last line of the function and return `false`. For example:

```
if(true == true){
  return true
}
```

This happened when stepping through in debug mode and also coded logs show the same result when not attached to a bugger.

After returning from the function every carries on as normal. No errors or warnings.

re-installing Android Studio, trying different simulators and physical Android devices didn't resolve the issue.

Renaming the function didn't resolve the issue.

Changing the return type of the function from `boolean` to `Boolean` did resolve the issue.

I'm well aware of the differences in these types, but I'm still perplexed as to to why this would this this problem. I can only assume changing the method signature in this way solved is something funky was happening at compile time.

I'll leave the question open for now, as even though changing the return type "fixed" the issue for me, i'm still not satisfied i'll know why... probably never will.

Hopefully somebody much more knowledgable on these sorts of issues can enlighten is all!

Comment: There is no issue with your code itself.

Comment: Your example works ok. The issue must me somewhere else. Please provide a broader example

Comment: sidenote, compare extensions with `.endsWith()`

Comment: What version of JDK do you have? If i remember correctly, some time ago .contains() was not applicable to String. Think pre-1.4 or something.

Comment: And you can also check compiled code in .class file.

Comment: I can't imagine a situation where you'd have these results, but remember that toLowerCase() is locale-dependent. In theory it would be possible for your computer to use a locale that would create problems. It should be toLowerCase(Locale.ROOT) for fully predictible results. Also, I'd display the length() of both Strings. There may be invisible characters at play here.

Comment: @VadimKotov I have just updated the question to show the entire function and perhaps it could be related to the enumeration the if is contained within. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @OliverMahoney Can you try running the code in a non-Android environment? With just the trimmed method and a main method calling that and printing the return value.

Comment: Moved the example out of the android env (http://tpcg.io/KjsoAu) and it works there.. I assume it's an issue with Android Studio Debugging or Compile.

Comment: FYI I have tried cleaning, re-building, reinstall.. This is a hellish issue indeed

Comment: @OliverMahoney Which JDK and Android Studio versions you're using to run the code?

Comment: @MikhailKholodkov Android Studio 3.1.3
Build #AI-173.4819257, built on June 4, 2018
JRE: 1.8.0_152-release-1024-b01 x86_64
JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
Mac OS X 10.13.5

Comment: @OliverMahoney Can you also post the byte-code produced from your **.class** file?

Comment: Also, try to change your loop to stream and see what happens: `return Arrays.stream(imageExtensions).anyMatch(s -> "Android App Image.jpg".toLowerCase().contains(s.toLowerCase()));`

Comment: Your example works just fine. The issue must be rooting from somewhere else.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you try using:

```
if (this.fileName.toLowerCase().contains(extension.toLowerCase()==true){
}
```

Comment: I have updated the question (Edit #2), it looks like the issue is related to compiler, but unsure at this point. Thanks for your input!

Comment: I have updated the question (Edit #2), it looks like the issue is related to compiler, but unsure at this point. Thanks for your input!

Answer (score 0):

Your search term produces false positive . Cause the file name string can have a substring that matches the extension. 
To avoid this you can prepend the search terms  by a dot.

`String[] imageExtensions = {".jpg", ".png", ".bmp", ".gif"};`

This will apperantly solve your problem .
It can produce false positive if there's any irregular use of  DOT in the file name. 
Hope it helps.

Comment: I have updated the question (Edit #2), it looks like the issue is related to compiler, but unsure at this point. Thanks for your input!